# Retrieving desired git commit message in pre-commit hook

Tags: git, git-commit

So if .git/hooks/pre-commit exists, then it will be run right after:

```
git commit -am "foobar"
```

is run.  So then how do I access the desired git commit message in the pre-commit?

I do some sleuthing and put this in .git/hooks/pre-commit and made the file executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "here is pre-commit hook"

env | sort

echo "args:"

echo $@

exit 1;
```

here are the env vars that are prefixed with "GIT"

```
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=@1558245421 -0700
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=alex@alexs-mac.local
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=Alexander Mills
GIT_EDITOR=:
GIT_EXEC_PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core
GIT_INDEX_FILE=/Users/alex/codes/interos/notifier-server/.git/index.lock
GIT_PREFIX=
```

and there seem to be no arguments to the script, because nothing gets logged after  `echo "args:"`...

so how do I access the *desired* commit message in a pre-commit hook?

**Specifically I am looking to bail from pre-commit if the commit-message does not have a good format.** If there is another hook that can do that, then that would be a good answer to this question.

Comment: Not precisely a dupe because the other question is a bit vague?

Comment: As it's said in the dup pre-commit hook doesn't have access to the commit message, {prepare-}commit-msg hooks do.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: the accepted answer points out the problem: in a pre-commit hook *there is no commit message yet!* The message is not created until after the pre-commit hook says that it's OK to proceed to next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most ideal git hooks situation - it would be nice if it were an env set and not an argument (git is not very thread-safe)

so forget about `.git/hooks/pre-commit` and instead use `.git/hooks/commit-msg`, and in there you might have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat $1
cat .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG

# the two above lines are the same
```

that is the git commit message that is still pending a commit.